# Is it possible to initialize the value in a lightning:inputRichText, like with a lightning:input or ui:inputText?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, richtextarea, inputrichtext

I can initialize the value of a `lightning:input` by doing this:

**Component:**

```
<lightning:input aura:id="subject" type="text" label="Subject" name="subject" />
```

**Controller:**

```
component.find("subject").set("v.value", "Hello!");
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

However, with `lightning:inputRichText`, when I follow the same pattern, the UI does not show the value, but if I `alert(component.find("body").get("v.value"))`, it shows the expected value.

**Component:**

```
<lightning:inputRichText aura:id="body" />
```

**Controller:**

```
component.find("body").set("v.value", "<p>This will be init properly once I switch to ContentNote</p>");
```

**Result:**

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? At the moment, the component [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputRichText.htm) doesn't have anything relevant besides listing `value` as an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code worked perfectly fine for me

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
 <lightning:inputRichText aura:id="body" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller code is as below

```
  ({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       component.find("body").set("v.value", "<p>This will be init properly once I switch to ContentNote</p>");
     }
 })
```

[image]

Comment: Hm - you're right. I added the `component.find("body").set` to the init method and it worked just fine. For some reason, it breaks when I have it in a separate method that's called from the parent component, using `aura:method`....anyway, that is a separate question, and you definitely answered the one that's posted here. I'm going to post a separate question for the specific case that you've helped me narrow it down to.

Comment: for placement of the update in another method see this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165758/lightninginputrichtext-value-can-be-initialized-from-init-method-but-not-from